# Where is the folder icon of dark mode located?

Tags: macos, customization

Where is the dark mode folder icon located?

The Dark Mode is so cool, but the blue folder icon is too bright in the whole black background. The grey one would be better for me.

So how do I change the icon?

In the early version,（OS X 10.6-10.11，macOS 10.12-10.13）
the path of the folder icon is
/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources

But in this folder, there is no Dark Mode folder icon. And, the icons of Light Mode are still here.

[image: folder icon of dark mode]
[image: folder icon of light mode(the same with old system icon)]

Who knows where I can find the dark icon, please?

An amazing thing is that when I use a grey folder icon that made by an artist in Deviantart.com to replace the icon of system itself(/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/GenericFolderIcon.icns), all the folder icons in finder windows had been changed into grey,and thay are light,the icon didn't change into dark mode with the system appearance. It seems that the icons that I think are only work in Light Mode are still work in the Dark Mode. But, they are available only in the files are system themselves.

Comment: Live graphics rendering?

Answer (score 0):

All system icons are located at: /System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/

To get there go to the Finder and select the Go menu option. From there select Go to Folder. This brings up a box and you can paste the above site into the box and hit return.

Comment: There is no folder icon of Dark Mode, there is only folder icon of light mode.

Comment: I thought I saw a dark mode folder but when I went back and looked I guess I was wrong.  Sorry.